# R - traverse data.frame levels in loop or vectorially?

Tags: r, loops, traversal, apply

I'm processing a data.frame of products called "`all`" whose first variable `all$V1` is a product family. There are several rows per product family, i.e. `length(levels(all$V1))` < `length(all$V1)`.

I want to traverse the data.frame and process by product family "`p`". I'm new to R, so I haven't fully grasped when I can do something vectorially, or when to loop. At the moment, I can traverse and get subsets by:

```
for (i in levels (all$V1)){
  p = all[which(all[,'V1'] == i), ];
  calculateStuff(p);
}
```

Is this the way to do this, or is there a groovy vectorial way of doing this with `apply` or something? There are only a few thousand rows, so performance gain is probably negligeable, but I'd like to devlop good habits for larger data ses.

Comment: Have a look at `aggregate`. It's basically a wrapper for `tapply` and calculates summary statistics for subsets of a data.frame. There are different ways of doing this and whether `aggregate` is suitable depends on what you want to calculate. But it's a good start, and quite convenient to use.

Comment: There is about a dozen ways to do this. Usually you'd use functions implementing the "split-apply-combine" concept. Look at packages plyr, dplyr, data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data:

```
all = data.frame(V1=c("a","b","c","d","d","c","c","b","a","a","a","d"))
```

'all' can be split by V1:

```
> ll = split(all, all$V1)
> ll
$a
   V1
1   a
9   a
10  a
11  a

$b
  V1
2  b
8  b

$c
  V1
3  c
6  c
7  c

$d
   V1
4   d
5   d
12  d
```

sapply can be used to analyze each component of list 'll'. Following finds number of rows in each component (which represents product family):

```
calculateStuff <- function(p){
  nrow(p)
}

> sapply(ll, calculateStuff)
a b c d 
4 2 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks, as it turns out `calculateStuff` does barplots and calculates a few basic statistics, and then outputs it all to a png. This looks like a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is unlikely to be much of a performance gain with the below, but it is at least more compact and returns the results of `calculateStuff` as a convenient list:

```
lapply(levels(all$V1), function(i) calculateStuff(all[all$V1 == i, ]) )
```

As @SimonG points out in his comment, depending on exactly what your `calculateStuff` function is, `aggregate` may also be useful to you if you want your results in the form of dataframe.